Boxer came out of prison for killing a person in a party, but only his sister trusts him now
It's about a man who was at a party. At one point he started to fight with another guy, he was a professional boxer and not allowed to fight and killed that other guy.
He was imprisoned for about 10-12 years, and when he came out there was no one near him because family and friends considered him not as the same man. The only person who trusted was his sister who had a smaller boy. He found work at a pizza place and was very loved by everyone. He never drank more than 10 years and in night he came home drunk, so his sister pulled him out. One day his grandson is hit by a car and died at the hospital.

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Any Day (2015)

Vian (Sean Bean), an ex-fighter who just served 12 years in jail for the drunken beating death of a man at a party. He’s gone sober in prison, and just wants to get his life back together. It takes some convincing, but his sister Bethley (Kate Walsh) agrees to let him crash on the couch. Vi draws closer to his nephew Jimmy (Nolan Gross). Vian gets a job at a pizza joint run by Roland (Tom Arnold), and the two quickly become close friends. He even meets a girl named Jolene (Eva Longoria) at the local grocery store.

Source: http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/any-day-2015

That's it !
Thx a lot

If you copy text wholesale from some external source (as it seems to be the case here), be sure to mention the source (preferably with link if possible) for proper attribution. You might also want to put the quoted parts into proper quote markup.

Hopefully corrected to standards
